# Why was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364623/facing-issue-with-z-index-value removed

Tags: support, specific-question

Why was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364623/facing-issue-with-z-index-value totally removed (while I was reading it) with no explanation?

Comment: *This post is hidden. It was deleted 7 mins ago by the post author.*

Comment: Also, the question lacks an MCVE, so it would've been closed and deleted at some point anyway.

Comment: Note that selecting text and copy still works if you're on the page when it goes.. "poof".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was deleted by its author.

They received a comment explaining why that question didn't meet our quality standards. That comment was correct as the question only offered links to a github repository and a website where we would "see" the problem.

Let's hope the OP improves their question by adding the code and an MCVE in their post before they undelete it again.